# Экранирование html символов в строках

Tags: java, android, экранирование

Есть JSON со строковым значением. В этом значении есть недопустимые символы (абзац, кавычки и т.п.).

Есть ли в Java способ автоматически закодировать эти символы в их HTML эквивалент (&quote и т.п.)? Применительно к Android.

Можно конечно использовать регулярки, но это долго и, как мне кажется, есть более простой способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В [Appache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) есть: [escapeHtml4​](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)).

   `escapeHtml4​(String input)` для `"bread" & "butter"` даст `&quot;bread&quot; &amp; &quot;butter&quot;`.
2. В [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) есть `HtmlEscapers.htmlEscaper().escape(source)`.